# Add keyboard shortcuts for the <kbd> tag

Tags: feature-request, edits, keyboard-shortcuts, kbd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Key equivalent for <kbd></kbd>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102841/key-equivalent-for-kbd-kbd)

Here's what I do in order to have the nice-looking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>:

1. Create text "`<kbd>`"
2. Highlight it
3. Copy it - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>
4. Paste it twice - (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>)*2
5. Insert text "`\"` between "`<`" and "`/`" of the second "`<kbd>`" tag
6. Insert text "`Ctrl` " between the two tags.
7. Highlight my creation ("`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`")
8. Copy it - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>
9. Paste it twice - (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>)*2
10. Insert text "`S`" between the last two tags

Can you help make me productive:

1. Create text "`CtrlS`"
2. Highlight "`Ctrl`"
3. Add "`<kbd>`" tag - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>magic key</kbd>
4. Highlight "`S`"
5. Add "`<kbd>`" tag - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>magic key</kbd>

Comment: You should include a `+` between the two `<kbd>` tags. It's much nicer that way.

Comment: @nyu I think the `+` is redundant. People included it just to indicate that they are talking keyboard combos, but since we have markup for that, well...

Comment: @Tshepang I think it isn't redunant.

Comment: @nyu Well, there is no better way of indicating that we are talking keyboard combos, if all you have is text. Now there is, so that makes the `+` redundant.

Comment: @Tshepang And what about the people who read questions/answers via RSS feeds, API-based apps, etc. -- some of which may or may not support <kbd> formatting?

Comment: Aside from @gclaghorn's good comment: I truly dislike the rendering of `<kbd>` (ugly and distracting), and am afraid that a keyboard shortcut might make people use it even more. (I have yet to see an OS that uses highlighting like that in menus. Why are we using it here?)

Comment: @Nyuszika7H: I like to use a `-` between the keys, but I agree that it looks messy when they're mashed together.

Comment: @gclaghorn: If the feed readers don't support the formatting, then tough beans.  If they support everything but `<kbd>`, they've already added the other formatting options and should also add `<kbd>`.

Comment: Agreed with the dupe, the other one's getting more attention and is clearer.