# Key equivalent for <kbd></kbd>

Tags: feature-request, edits, keyboard-shortcuts, kbd

The editor has key equivalents for all the buttons (<kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> for bold, etc.). However, the most annoying thing to type is `<kbd></kbd>`, but there's no key equivalent for this. Can haz?

Comment: But how often do you need to use it?  So far, every control that is used most frequently in the editor to improve the format of the post has a shortcut.  How often do we really need to use the `<kbd>` tags?  I mean _really_ need it.  I just don't see this being accepted by the team if they think it was necessary to remove shortcuts to save (which is much more useful than `<kbd>` tags IMHO).

Comment: Are you saying `<kbd>` *doesn't* improve post quality? I was going to edit a post to add `<kbd>` tags to improve it, but found it annoying when I had more than one set to add. This is also especially noticeable on sites that tend to use a lot of keyboard shortcuts, such as AskDifferent. Also, what do you mean by "to remove shortcuts to save"?

Comment: No, I'm saying it's not used as much as the rest of the other controls that do have shortcuts.  At one point, [it was possible to save drafts through a keyboard shortcut](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69831/is-the-save-draft-keyboard-binding-broken/69885#69885).  If you look at Jeff's answer, it seems highly likely that this would be rejected for pretty much the same reason, to save on the code size.

Comment: @Jeff This is *very* different from saving drafts.  All the shortcut has to do is insert the tiny text snippet.

Comment: @Matthew: I know that, the point I was trying to make was that the shortcut was removed to reduce the size of the code for a not-so-important feature.  Even small insignificant things such as this get shot down, especially if it's something that a user script can fix.  I'm rather skeptical they'd add in another keyboard shortcut for a feature that isn't used on a regular basis but rather for something that would be used every day.

Comment: What on earth is wrong with creating an entirely fictitious kbd key using the kbd tag itself??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new [Stacks Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380295/announcing-the-stacks-editor-beta-release), the shortcut Keyboard <kbd>Ctrl-'</kbd> is introduced.
Reference: https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/51
Using the new shortcut you are able to create the Keyboard text in the editor.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Keyboard shortcut added - image]

**GIF for reference**:

[image: Keyboard shortcut added - gif]

Answer (score 12):

There's a userscript for this. It adds a keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>), and a ***kbd*** button like this:

[image: kbd button appearance]

**Update:** The script now also adds a few other useful markdown shortcuts as well.  See [the post about the script at Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/q/3341/7653).

[Directly install it from GitHub.](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/raw/master/Add_kbd_sup_sub_shortcuts.user.js) (Requires *Tampermonkey*, or *Violentmonkey*, or equivalent.)

Answer (score 2):

If every possible feature had an associated UI button to do the same thing, then there would be a stronger and stronger precedent to *always* have a UI button to do every little editing task. Then it would be impossible to add a new feature without *also* adding a new UI button. This is a fast track to a cluttered, unusable UI.

Also, people have been successfully training their fingers to type open-close HTML tags for twenty years. Get used to it.

Comment: Agreed, and I don't need a button, I'd just like a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score -4):

Adding a keyboard shortcut would probably also include making people aware of its existence? Or make people who already knew about `<kbd>` use it more often? Please, no, don't increase using `<kbd>`.

(The formatting only looks acceptable to me on the Apple site. But even there it's not really needed, I feel. On all other sites: <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>, and hence, for me, annoying. As an aside: I see abuse of irrelevant inline tags too. Like [here](/questions/tagged/here). I rarely see a true need for `<kbd`> or `[tag]`.)

Comment: I suspect that this (the possibility of increasing awareness about the `<kbd>` tag) is *precisely* the reason that we don't have an easier way to use it. Jeff disabled `<kbd>` *completely* here on Meta once, citing [ridiculous overuse](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1974#1974), and he'd probably do the same thing across the network if it became a problem. Given that I like it and wish for it to stay around, I'm not sure a shortcut is a good idea...

Comment: @Cody What would you say about that though? [Getting to Windows 7 shutdown menu with the keyboard](http://superuser.com/questions/328818/getting-to-windows-7-shutdown-menu-with-the-keyboard) (see Jeff's edits)

Comment: Nice find, @slhck. And, I wonder if that's about testing a keyboard shortcut; editing in HTML is not a fun task...

Comment: what on earth is wrong with using the kbd tag itself?? thus:-
<kbd>kbd</kbd>

Comment: OK simple answer it don't work!!

Comment: yet <kbd>caps Lock</kbd> does or does it??

Comment: Umm... not only the apple site. Many software related sites, like Super User, Graphic Design and Blender  to name a few, all use the kbd functionality *a lot*.