# Please add a toolbar button or keyboard shortcut for the Keyboard style

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editor, kbd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Key equivalent for <kbd></kbd>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102841/key-equivalent-for-kbd-kbd)

I originally posted this on [Meta.Superuser.com](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1454/please-add-a-toolbar-button-or-keyboard-shortcut-for-the-keyboard-style) almost a year ago where it was upvoted a lot. Unfortunately, it has not been implemented, or any official feedback received. I think it may be beneficial to other StackExchange web sites and therefore I am posting here for others to discuss/think about.

When writing answers, one of the items that takes me the longest is to type the keyboard code:

```
<kbd> </kbd>
```

I am not saying it takes hours, or is a major problem, but it is an inconvenience and I think that this would make an excellent addition to the shortcut bar, or at least a new hidden combo key.