# Add a "format as keystroke" button to the post editor

Tags: feature-request, editor, kbd

I edited a question on SO. My edit was approved, but only after it was modified to change an instance of `code formatting` to <kbd>keystroke formatting</kbd>. I did not know how to format as a keystroke, so it appears there is a hidden combination of SO HTML that does it. At that point, I looked it up through edit, but have already forgotten what it is.

Could this be added as a button to the WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard Glyphs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5527/keyboard-glyphs)

Comment: @Arjan: not a duplicate. My question is not about how it's done - it's about getting it into the editor as a standard feature.

Comment: Thanks for editing my post. Now it's almost as good to start a book with it being the intro paragraph. :) But why did you remove `feature-request` tag?

Comment: Ah, my bad: given that you did not use `<kbd>` anywhere in your original post, I thought you were asking about how it works. (So did blahdiblah in their answer.) Very well then: duplicate of [Please add a toolbar button or keyboard shortcut for the Keyboard style](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108644/please-add-a-toolbar-button-or-keyboard-shortcut-for-the-keyboard-style), but that has been closed...

Comment: @Arjan: if you are so desperate to find a duplicate, look no further: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102841/key-equivalent-for-kbd-kbd, but I think this question is better formulated due to numerous edits by fellow members (thanks to everybody who contributed).

Comment: I actually think that is *not* a duplicate, but indeed the one I linked to is closed as a duplicate of that one. And please don't blame people from misinterpreting your original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for the <kbd>keyboard markup</kbd>.

Which is to say:

```
<kbd>keyboard markup</kbd>
```

That's probably not used frequently enough to warrant a button on the WYSIWYG editor, but it might be nice to document it better.  Right now it's only documented via [Advanced Markup - Inline HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html) as one of the supported tags.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still think it needs to be there, because it makes sense to have it there. So my call is make it available and we'll see if it becomes popular. If it contributes to interface clutter, you could hide it in advanced options of the editor. Some `ellipsis ...` or `More >>` arrow or similar.