# Keyboard shortcut for key formatting?

Tags: discussion, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut to apply keyboard formatting to text? E.g. Rather of manually typing the opening and closing `<kbd>` tags, is there a way to automatically apply them by highlighting the character(s) to be keyboard formatted and pressing a shortcut so that the keyboard tags are automatically applied? (e.g. similarly to we can for bold and italic)

Comment: No, there is none, none of the supported HTML tags have keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Markdown syntax for \`<kbd>foo</kbd>\`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130074/282094) https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78068/282094 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/346457/282094

Answer (score 3):

#### Is there a shortcut to apply keyboard formatting to text?

Yes, if you install the [Add_kbd_sup_sub_shortcuts.user.js](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/blob/master/Add_kbd_sup_sub_shortcuts.user.js) script:

> This script adds buttons and keyboard shortcuts that make it easy to
>   add/remove:
>
> - `<kbd>` tags
> - Superscripts and subscripts
> - `<del>` tags
> - `<br>` tags
> - `&emsp;`
>
> when editing posts.
>
> Click the button or press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> on the keyboard
>   and `<kbd></kbd>` will be inserted at the cursor.
>
> If text is selected, it will be wrapped by the  tags instead.

[image]

Source [script - \, Superscript and Subscript, markup shortcuts - Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/3341/kbd-superscript-and-subscript-markup-shortcuts)